# Idiomatic Way to Load Widgets?

Tags: gwt

What is the idiomatic way to load widgets in a GWT application? I want to be able to have a navigation bar on the top of the application and whenever a user clicks a link in the navigation bar I want the content section of the application to load the target widget/component. Essentially, I'm looking for the GWT equivalent of loading a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way is [to build MVP-based application](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) using activities and places.